# Magento 2 : Cache types (When to clear which cache)

Tags: magento2, cache

Here i am talking about magento 2 default cache.

I am looking for a clean idea, when to clear which cache.
For example if change made to layout file, we can simply execute one

```
php bin/magento c:c layout
```

So, i need idea when i change to any model or php file which cache type need to be cleared ?
also for phtml/js/css files ?

Understanding this will save some time in development as it need to clear one/two cache type not all cache type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that once you understand what the cache type holds, you can easily adjust your development process. The [devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html#config-cli-subcommands-cache-clean-over.) provide a comprehensive description and also instructions on when to clear a particular type of cache (for most of them, the others are pretty intuitive):

- **Configuration** - Magento collects configuration from all modules, merges it, and saves the merged result to the cache. This cache also contains store-specific settings stored in the file system and database. **Clean or flush this cache type after modifying configuration files.**
- **Layout** - Compiled page layouts (that is, the layout components from all components). **Clean or flush this cache type after modifying layout files.**
- **Block HTML output** - HTML page fragments per block. **Clean or flush this cache type after modifying the view layer.**
- **Collections data** - Results of database queries. If necessary, Magento cleans up this cache automatically, but third-party developers can put any data in any segment of the cache. **Clean or flush this cache type if your custom module uses logic that results in cache entries that Magento cannot clean.**
- **DDL** - Database schema. If necessary, Magento cleans up this cache automatically, but third-party developers can put any data in any segment of the cache. **Clean or flush this cache type after you make custom changes to the database schema.**
- **Compiled Config** - Compilation configuration
- **Entity attribute value (EAV)** - Metadata related to EAV attributes (for example, store labels, links to related PHP code, attribute rendering, search settings, and so on). **You should not typically need to clean or flush this cache type.**
- **Page cache** - Generated HTML pages. If necessary, Magento cleans up this cache automatically, but third-party developers can put any data in any segment of the cache. **Clean or flush this cache type after modifying code level that affects HTML output. It is recommended to keep this cache enabled because caching HTML improves performance significantly.**
- **Reflection** - Removes a dependency between the Webapi module and the Customer module.
- **Translations** - After merging translations from all modules, the merger cache will be cleaned.
- **Integration configuration** - Compiled integrations. **Clean or flush this cache after changing or adding integrations.**
- **Integration API configuration** - Compiled integration APIs configuration of the Store’s Integrations.
- **Web services configuration** - Caching the Web API Structure.
- **Customer Notification** - Temporary notifications that appear in the user interface.

You also have **the static files cache** separately:

> Besides the cached files, in theme development process developers also deal with other saved files - static view files that are preprocessed and published to the var/view_preprocessed and pub/static directories correspondingly. In most cases when working on a custom theme, for example, if you are only working on styles, you do not need to clean cache, but need to clean the previously preprocessed and published static view files. **To clean them, run grunt clean  or manually clear the pub/static and var/view_preprocessed directories.**

And the **JS/CSS cache** used when your Magento install is set to use merged strategy. This type of cache can be either from the **admin -> system -> cache management -> additional cache management - flush js/css cache OR by clearing the browser cache.**

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: you're welcome!